# How is this definition of a constant divided by zero called?

Tags: arithmetic, definition, infinity

I divide a constant by zero.
One example is the following:
2/0
My father told me he learned at school earlier that the result is "not defined".
If I enter this arithmetic problem in Wolfram Alpha, I will get ∞ as result. How is this kind of definition called?

Comment: WA is probably interpreting it as $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^+}\left(\dfrac 2 x\right)$. Your father is correct.

Comment: You can do that if you work in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. Doing this you lose some properties ($\bar{R}$ is not a field) but is useful for some purposes. Doing this you define $\frac{a}{0}=\infty$ which is just that, a definition. Adding an element to a set is a very useful mathematical tool as can be seen in the concept of Alexandroff extension (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) altough this is not directly related with the question you are asking.

Comment: @GitGud And how do you explain that the result of a constant divided by ∞ is zero on Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @Adolfo You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm Same thing, WA probably interprets it as $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\left(\dfrac 2 x\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotient $x=b/a$ is defined as the unique solution to the equation $ax=b$ for $a$ and $b$ real numbers. Now if $a = 0$ and $b\neq 0$ then there is no $x$ for which $$ax=b.$$ This is because for every real number $x$, $$0\cdot x = 0 \neq b$$ thus there is no $x$ that would satisfy this equation, and we say $b/0$ is undefined.

Finally for the case of $a=b=0$ we can see that any real number $x$ satisfies $a\cdot x = b$, since both sides are zero. So in this case, any number $x$ can be chosen as the solution. Hence in this case as well, we cannot write $x=0/0$ since there is no unique number to pick for this situation.

---

The interpretation that $2/0$ is $\infty$ arrises when you take limits. It's a shorthand of saying $\lim_{x\to0^+} 2/x=\infty$, but it is not strictly speaking $2/0$ which is undefined.

Comment: You _could_ add a little note about $0/0$ to create the perfect answer ;) (+1)

Comment: Edited and Added :)

Comment: Very nice answer, explains it without any "advanced" concepts and without too much fuss :)